# Program not recognising geckodriver in PATH when calling a python file from a bash script

Tags: python, bash, selenium, environment-variables, geckodriver

I am trying to call a python test file using a bash script. The script currently reads-

```
python C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BE\BE\Tests\test_BE.py %*
```

The python script runs perfectly when called by itself from the command line. The file uses selenium webdriver and geckodriver, and both are in the PATH variable. (As evidenced by the file working fine when called via command line). I also added C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\ as that was suggested in other stack solutions to similar problems. However, when I run the bash file, I get the error that:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Messaage: 'geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I am unsure how to resolve this as the executable is already in the path. Any insight would be very appreciated.

**EDIT** I currently define the path to geckodriver, and the driver, etc. with:

```
gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver'))
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko+'.exe')
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the full path to the executable in the script?

Comment: I have not... I did not realize I could. How would I do so?

Comment: I currently call geckodriver in the file using: gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver')), which has been working fine on multiple machines when calling the script directly from the command line

Comment: If you know exactly where the .exe file is, remove gecko from the executable_path variable and enter the full path instead.

Comment: Also echo $PATH on the command line will give you information regarding whether your path contains the neccesary directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the solution as Raman suggested was to remove the gecko variable, and place the full path to geckodriver.exe within the driver variable, ie:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='C:\path\to\executable')
```

Once I did this the python scripts worked perfectly.

Comment: Great Cassie, I'm glad I could help.